# Maximum of N iid random random variables with Gumbel distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I know that the maximum of iid random variables has Gumbel distribution. For example, this is true when iid random variables have Exponential distribution.

Does this hold when iid random variables have Gumbel distribution themselves?

Let's say there are $N$ iid random variables with distribution $X_n\sim Gumbel(\mu, \beta),~n=1,...,N$. What is the distribution of $\text{max}_n~X_n$? If it is also a Gumbel distribution, say $Gumbel(\mu_{\text{max}}, \beta_{\text{max}})$, how are parameters $\mu_{\text{max}}$ and $\beta_{\text{max}}$ related to $\mu$ and $\beta$?

I tried to find an answer in multiple textbooks, but could not find anything.

Comment: A simple thought is that if a Gumbel distribution is the limiting distribution of the maximum of $M$ i.i.d. exponential distributed random variables, then the maximum of $N$ i.i.d. such Gumbel distributed random variables is  the limiting distribution of the maximum of $MN$ i.i.d. exponential distributed random variables so a Gumbel distribution

Comment: That's a really nice way to put it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this hold when iid random variables have Gumbel distribution themselves?

Yes, due to the condition "iid".

> Without the condition "iid", that's not true.  You may consult [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/221666) for details.

The CDF of $X_i \sim {\rm Gumbel}(\mu,\beta)$ is
$$ F_i(x) = \exp(-\exp((\mu - x)/\beta)).$$
Then the CDF for $Y_n = \max_{i = 1,\dots,n} X_i$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) &= \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \le y) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n F_i(y) \\
&= \exp(-n\exp((\mu-y)/\beta)) \\
&= \exp(-\exp((\mu+\beta \ln n-y)/\beta))
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore, $Y_n \sim {\rm Gumbel}(\mu+\beta\ln n, \beta)$.

Comment: Thanks for a nice and clean answer!